# Can't connect to bluetooth switch

Tags: bluetooth, home-automation

I have a Pi3 running Jessie and I'm trying to connect to this plug, [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00PG50OSM/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PG50OSM). I've been able to pair and trust the device, when issuing the connect command, it initially says its connected, but then says the connect failed. Here's what I see:

```
[bluetooth]# connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[CHG] Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I do see these errors in syslog:

```
Jan 22 17:03:09 rpi bluetoothd[1056]: 8C:DE:52:20:C6:89: error updating    services: Connection refused (111)

Jan 22 17:03:11 rpi kernel: [   65.388976] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c1a tx timeout
```

I've done a firmware update using rpi-update and I've updated my installation as well. Much googling has not turned up anything the seems to help.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the Amazon questions, you cannot use this adapter as it is not supported, and "Plugable" is misrepresented.

I don't know if this is correct, but it appears as if you cannot use this with a Raspberry Pi.

*Quote from Amazon:*

> Can i control it on raspbian os using python?
>
> No. Plugable misrepresents the open sourcing of this particular product.
>
> By David J. on December 28, 2016